# Hosting Qlik Sense Mashup

Tags: visualization, embedded-resource, qliksense

I want to understand the functioning of Qlik Mashups. We have a Qlik sense enterprise server and a limited number of named licenses. I have created a mashup and now wish to share it online with clients or other users who do not have a license/token. Understandably, it will not work but I have seen websites which have qlik interactive content. How is that done?

Will an OEM partnership help in this case, if yes, then how? I do have the option to get an OEM partnership but I am not sure if we are ready to invest in that just as yet. Are there any other options?

Appreciate the support.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems the best way to go ahead was to get the licenses. We also plan to get a un-named license and let it fetch tokens for the users visiting the site.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a another license plan which based on qlik analytics platform server,  then you can provide access privilege to your mashup page to unlimited number of users.
You can contact any seller of Qlik sense to get information of this kind of license, as I know the cost is quite high.